# How to forward data from one jsp A to jsp B and then all data to final servlet?

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I have two JSP pages `A` and `B` and also a Servlet.

---

The flow is like this:

User fill in some information in page A

Then the user fill in some other information in page B

After the user finishes B, he/she will click a button and submit all data (from both A and B) to the Servlet.

---

How should I design this?

My plan is

In A's `next` button, it is actually a `<a>` tag with link to the href of B. All information from A should be passed to B via that link. I don't know how to do this step.

In B's `finish` button, it is a form input submit button. I don't know whether I can or how I add A's data into this form.

---

Anyone can help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Which framework are you using for this development?

Comment: @AhamedMustafaM Just simple JSP + Tomcat + Servlet.

Comment: Why can't you have a form in A ? If you don't want a form in A, then you can use Javascript to construct the url to include a query string, when the link is clicked.

Comment: @rickz If I have a form in A, can I submit all info to page B? or you mean I have a form in A, then I first submit partial information in A to Servelet, then from B to Servelet?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. One way is to have form in A and submit to B. B can get parameters from A and put them into hidden inputs in it's form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your A.jsp create a link, for e.g.: `<a href="B.jsp?param1=value1&param2=value2">Go to B</a>`
Pass your parameters from URL.

In B.jsp use expression language to get parameters values:

```
<form action="FinalServlet" method="post">

   <input type="text" name="p" value="your value"/>

   <input type="hidden" name="p1" value="${param.param1}"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="p2" value="${param.param2}"/>

   .......

   <input type="submit" value="Finish"/>

</form>
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

If you want to use a form with input fields in A.jsp:

```
<form action="B.jsp" method="post">

   <input type="text" name="param1" value="value1"/>
   <input type="text" name="param2" value="value2"/>

   .......

   <input type="submit" value="Finish"/>

</form>
```

You will receive parameters in B.jsp using the same EL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The info user need to fill are all written via <input>, how can I get the values from those input and give it as parameter of <a>?

Comment: Why do you need to do so? You can pass the values from input fields the same. Create a form in A.jsp, create some input fields and in B.jsp receive them with expression language: ${param.param1}. It will work as well.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Yes, I can use form as well, but I am not a professional on jsp or html development. The "next" button I am using cannot be inside the form. I put it somewhere else to adapt to the overall design lol. In your original way, could you please tell me how do I get those parameters for <a> tag?

Comment: You can write some kind of javascript to put the parameters to <a> tag but for it you will have to do some searching becouse I can not think of any at the moment. :/ but I still don't understand why you need to do so. If you want a link   to work as a submit, you can use java script to submit the form for e.g.: <a href="#" onclick="document.forms["myform"].submit();">. "myform" should be the name of the form. <form name="myform" .....>

Comment: Check this how to submit form using javascript: http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

Comment: Yeah, thanks Paulius, haha, I got it working. Your "submit form using javascript" is exactly what I want. Sorry I am a newbie and I was just asked by my boss to implement this.

Comment: Also, do you know in B.jsp, how can I get the parameters from A and put them as the hidden input?

Comment: I am glad that you got it working :) I have already showed you how to get parameters from A.jsp, use expression language. Look closely into the answer.